# how to properly place a specific column into a bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble placing a column into a bootstrap 3 grid.
Specifically - column "Row 2 Col 4".

```
  <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #777;margin-right: 2px">
            <h3>Row 2 Col 1</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 other" style="background: #765;min-height: 300px">
                    <h3>Row 2 Col 1 Nested 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 other" style="background: #755;min-height: 300px">
                    <h3>Row 2 Col 1 Nested 2</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 other">
            <h3>Row 2 Col 2</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 other" style="background: #770;min-height: 540px">
                    <h3>Row 2 Col 2 Nested 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 other" style="background: #760">
                    <h3>Row 2 Col 2 Nested 2</h3>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #737;margin-right: 2px">
            <h3>Row 2 Col 4</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My sample: https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/84wLqsjk/#&togetherjs=gf9y1cvQIK
I need to have this column right under "Row 1 Col 4".
What should I fix here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use custom `margin`s on bootstrap `col-*` and still expect them to work.
They're carefully tailored to sum up `100%` of row width when you reach 12 columns. Add margins to them and they will exceed `100%` row width, making the last item float on next row.

Remove `margin:2px` placed inline on your `.col-*`s and it will work as expected.

If you want to keep the white space displayed between the columns, consider using wrappers for your content, placed inside `.col-*`s. And, of course, moving the `background`s to the wrappers. `padding` on `.col-*`s is also a viable option.

---

Edit: after giving it some thought, I realized the fastest way to achieve what you want (also considering what you already have) is by using `border`s on cols. [Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/84wLqsjk/1/).

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg, not 100% sure you get notified about changes on answers to your questions, so adding a note here to make sure you read it in due time, before you achieve it yourself. See edit to answer. Cheers!

Comment: This helps. Thank you!